# prevent react remount when parent reorders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm trying to write a component that sometimes reorders it's children, something like:

```
class Reorder extends React.PureComponent {
    construnctor() {
        this.state = {reorder: false}
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.reorder) {
            return 
                <div>
                    <div key=0>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
                    <div key=1>{this.props.children[1]}</div>
                </div>
        } else {
            return 
                <div>
                    <div key=1>{this.props.children[1]}</div>
                    <div key=0>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
                </div>
        }
    }
}

class notifyOnMount extends React.PureComponent {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(`mounted ${this.props.name}`)
    }
}
```

and using it by:

```
<Reorder reorder={shouldReorder}>
    <notifyOnMount key="0" name="first" />
    <notifyOnMount key="1" name="second" />
</Reorder>
```

but in the above example I keep getting re-renders from both components every time shouldReorder changes. I need to have the children always mounted for them to behave properly. Why do they keep re-rendering?

Comment: because of your condional rendering your component is remounted again

Comment: This looks like an issue with the child components, as rerendering should not cause remounting as long as the rendered structure remains the same and the keys are handled appropriately. Does a `this.forceUpdate()` on `Reorder` also cause remounting?

Comment: @Oblosys `this.forceUpdate()` does not call constructor, componentWillMount or render of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
Instead of using conditional rendering, make use of css property to reorder like

```
class Reorder extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {reorder: false}
    }

    render() {
            const styles = {
               display: flex,
               flex-direction: this.state.reorder ? 'row': 'row-reverse'
            }
            return 
                <div style={styles}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
        } 
}
```

**Method 2**

Another thing that you could do is render the children using an array and apply your reorder logic on the array items

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: [{name: 'first', key: 0}, {name: 'second', key: 1}]
    }
    reorderData = () => {
        const data = [...this.state.data];
        const newData = data.reverse();
        this.setState({ data: newData })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
         if(this.state.shouldReorder !== prevState.shouldReorder) {
             this.reorderData();
         }
    }
    render() {
        return <Reorder reorder={shouldReorder}>
            {this.state.data.map((item, index) => <NotifyOnMount key={item.key} name={item.name} />)}
        </Reorder>
    }
}
```

and

```
class Reorder extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
            return 
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
        } 
}
```

Comment: And what if I have many children and I want to order them by some logic?

Comment: `I want to order them by some logic` in such cases you would need to handle your logic differently in child, since each time you conditionally render them, they will remount

Comment: No way around that?

Comment: @GuinNess, There is one more that I know, I updated my answer for that, but certainly conditional rendering is not the way.